# INVALID_ARGUMENT_TYPE on ContentVersion insert in test method, varies by sandbox

Tags: apex, unit-test, sandbox, files

I'm getting an exception in one sandbox and not another, anytime I try to insert a `ContentVersion`.  I created a simple test to distill this down to its essence:

```java
@isTest
public class SampleTest {
    @isTest
    static void runTest() {
        insert new ContentVersion(
            Title = 'test1',
            PathOnClient = 'test1.txt',
            ContentLocation = 'S',
            VersionData = Blob.valueOf('test')
        );
    }
}
```

Here's the exception I'm getting in one of the sandboxes:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: 
INVALID_ARGUMENT_TYPE, The argument is null or invalid.: []  
Class.SampleTest.runTest: line 5, column 1
```

Both sandboxes are on Winter '21.  The one with the error was recently refreshed.  Due to the number of teams that push changes to production on a regular basis, any number of things could be different from one sandbox to the other.  What kinds of environment differences could lead to this difference in behavior?

Comment: Do you have a trigger or Process/Flow on ContentVersion that maybe isn't deployed in some orgs?

Comment: Great suggestion!  It did turn out to be an issue with a trigger on the `ContentDocument` object.  The trigger code was calling a method whose signature had changed as part of another effort, so the code was invalid.  Hence the cryptic failure message.

Comment: Please provide and accept an answer or delete your post. Unresolved questions are ugly.